# OpenIdDict - Device Code Flow, how to change user_code length

Tags: oauth-2.0, openiddict

I'm using OpenIdDict (version 5.0.1) to implement the OAuth 'Device Code Flow'.
The /device endpoint is returning this data:

```
{
   "device_code": "lyJe_PgWGfOblSS6PhX67hF_ebKjTN1UZeMO3KWtJt0",
   "user_code": "8539-7540-1784",
   "verification_uri": "..."
}
```

The "user_code" has 12 digits, it is quite long, considering that it must be inserted manually by the user.

I've tried to customize the /device endpoint, but this seems not to be supported by OpenIdDict, as it is possible for example for the /authorize enpoint, using EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()

```
options
 .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
 .AllowDeviceCodeFlow();

options.UseAspNetCore()
 .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough();
```

I've not found any other options that permits to customize the 'user_code' format.

Is it possible to generate a shorter user_code? for example: "6745-3454"?

Answer (score 1):

> I've not found any other options that permits to customize the 'user_code' format.
> Is it possible to generate a shorter user_code? for example: "6745-3454"?

[OpenIddict 5.4.0](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/releases/tag/5.4.0) introduced the ability to customize the user codes charset, length and display format:

```cs
options.SetUserCodeCharset(
[
    "B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M",
    "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "X", "Z"
]);
```

```cs
options.SetUserCodeLength(7);
```

```cs
options.SetUserCodeDisplayFormat("{0}{1} - {2}{3}{4} - {5}{6}");
```

Note: using a lower length reduces the entropy of the generated user codes and increases chances of seeing collisions.

Comment: Thanks you for this improvement!
As workaround, we had customized the default *EventHandler* as shown below, but now we are going to remove it and use the options.SetUserCodeLength() method 

services.AddOpenIddict()
 .AddCore(options =>
 {
  ...
 })
 .AddServer(options =>
 {
  options.RemoveEventHandler(AttachTokenPayload.Descriptor);
  **options.AddEventHandler(QamfAttachTokenPayload.Descriptor);**
 }

Comment: @Claudio glad you like it! Yeah, removing custom handlers now that it's a built-in feature is a good idea.